# Run hiphop on server

Tags: hiphop

I have installed the hip-hop php on my **ubunut server 12.4** now what i want to do is to point a directory to run all my file through hiphop

i have tried the command 
"**hhvm my_script.php**" 
it is working fine

but i want to run hip-hop in background so that all the file on my web server will be complied and run through hip-hop

Please do explain me how can i do this and if possible please post a detailed tutorial of how it will work and what changes i have to make it on my server

i refereed the git-hub link for installation
**https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki**

Comment: Have you found the answer?